# Wildfly can't find JAX-WS

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, jax-ws

I'm migrating an old system with Java7/JBoss7 to Java8/Wildfly14, it compiles ok, but when I try to deploy I get the following error:

```
ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."rt-app-war-9.2-SNAPSHOT.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."rt-app-war-9.2-SNAPSHOT.war".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "rt-app-war-9.2-SNAPSHOT.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:151)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1736)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1698)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1556)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/ws/WebServiceException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1825)
    at org.jboss.as.jsf.deployment.JSFComponentProcessor.deploy(JSFComponentProcessor.java:106)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:144)
    ... 8 more

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException from [Module "deployment.rt-app-war-9.2-SNAPSHOT.war" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:255)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
```

The jar which contains      is javaee-api-7.0.jar and it is in my pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

When I hit ctrl+shift+T in Eclipse and type "javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException", it finds it in that jar, so I don't understand why Wildfly says it couldn't find the class.

Am I missing something ?

Comment: Are you deploying from Eclipse or does this happen also when deploying the WAR file to `standalone/deployments`?

Comment: @MišoStankay I just tried, it also happens when deploying the WAR directly to jboss.
Weird thing: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException is also a part of JDK 1.8, there is no way it wouldn't find it!

Comment: I suggest you isolate the failing part of the code to the github repo and send the link, so I can run it on my own.

Comment: Do you have Java 10 or 11 on your machine because this smells like your WildFly is running with one of those...

Comment: @SteveC I had Java 11 and also thought it could be something related, but even after removing it, the problem continues.
For now I just manually added the jar inside web-inf/lib so I can continue working, but before it goes to acceptance environment I need to figure this out =/

Comment: Are you using any jboss/wildfly deployment descriptors?

Comment: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/279024

Comment: http://docs.wildfly.org/14/Developer_Guide.html#JAX_WS_JBoss_Modules_and_WS_applications

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is because you don't have a dependency to JAX-WS API. Can you please try adding the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution. I did this, then war file is deployed successfully

jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="webservices"/>
            <subsystem name="logging"/>
            <subsystem name="resteasy"/>
            <subsystem name="jaxrs" />
        </exclude-subsystems>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="javax.jws.api" export="true"/>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```